# ubuntu 15.04 vivid vervet pavillion x360 system settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 15.04, system-settings

I have been using Ubuntu 15.04 for a while on a Pavillion x360. Everything worked perfect! After the last time I ran:

sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade

I started getting error messages. That automatically requested me to submit them, which I did.

I removed alsa-base and pulseaudio. Re-installed them both, but also installed pavucontrol. When I entered System Settings and entered Sound and Display. The panels are transparent. The sound devices both on-board pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0c)

and HDMI sound no longer were present.

Both devices still work, but the panels on system-settings are not working right.

Is there a way to have ubuntu restore to install defaults?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to fix it, but it isn't the solution I was looking for. I would have like to know how to properly troubleshoot the problem or understand where and how it originated.

I basically re-installed gnome desktop and rebooted.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-enviornment
```

Hope this helps some one else.

Cheers